# discord.py - How do I add a kick/ban reason?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to add an optional `reason` message to the `+kick` command when banning a member of a Discord room. My attempted code is below.

Command and example usage:

```
+kick <username> <reason>
+kick @Pine#1337 Spamming Messages in Wrong Channel.
```

Code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, arg, reason):
author = ctx.message.author
data = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
embed = discord.Embed(name="MEMBER_KICKED", description="------------------------------------------------------", color=0x00ff00)
embed.set_author(name="MEMBER_KICKED:\nMember Kicked Successfully")
embed.add_field(name="Kicked by: ", value="{}".format(author.mention), inline=False)
embed.add_field(name="Kicked: ", value="<@{}>".format(user.id), inline=False)
embed.add_field(name="Reason: ", value="{}\n------------------------------------------------------".format(arg), inline=False)
embed.set_footer(text="Requested by {} \a {}".format(author, data), icon_url=author.avatar_url)
await bot.say(embed=embed)
channel = discord.utils.get(user.server.channels, name="logs")
embed = discord.Embed(name="MEMBER_KICKED", description="------------------------------------------------------", color=0xff0000)
embed.set_author(name="MEMBER_KICKED:\nMember Kicked")
embed.add_field(name="Kicked by: ", value="{}".format(author.mention), inline=False)
embed.add_field(name="Kicked: ", value="<@{}>".format(user.id), inline=False)
embed.add_field(name="Reason: ", value="{}\n------------------------------------------------------".format(arg), inline=False)
embed.set_footer(text="Kicked at {}".format(data))
await bot.send_message(channel, embed=embed)
if user.bot == False:
  embed = discord.Embed(name="KICKED", description="------------------------------------------------------", color=0xff0000)
  embed.set_author(name="KICKED:\nYou've been Kicked")
  embed.add_field(name="Kicked by: ", value="{}".format(author.mention), inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Kicked in: ", value="{}".format(user.server), inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Reason: ", value="{}\n------------------------------------------------------".format(arg), inline=False)
  embed.set_footer(text="Kicked at {}".format(data))
  await bot.send_message(user, embed=embed)
if user.bot == True:
  pass
reason = arg
await bot.kick(user, reason=reason)
```

Error:

> TypeError: kick() missing 1 required 1 keyword-only argument 'reason'

Comment: What do you want to happen to the kick message? This is something that the rewrite branch supports, but the async branch doesn't.  See [`Guild.kick`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Guild.kick)

Comment: when someone types the command, for example `+ban <user> <reason>` it bans an member and the reason its the arg

Comment: edited: fix title grammar, give background information, fix code blocks

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `reason` parameter
The reason you're kicking gets caught in `arg`

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, arg):
  reason = arg
```

Comment: `TypeError: kick() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reason'`

Comment: There is no `reason` argument in the `kick` method. Just do `await bot.kick(user)`

Answer (score 0):

Ban/Kick reasons were introduced by Discord after the feature freeze for the async branch. They exist only on the [discord.py-rewrite](/questions/tagged/discord.py-rewrite) branch.  There they are a keyword argument:

```
@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason):
  await user.kick(reason=reason)
```